# Magento2 Ui Component Color Grid Row

Tags: magento2, grid

I have a custom logger for magento2.
Now i want for in the admin grid to change the table row color based on the status of the row.
For example a row got status: warning, the table row has to be orange. What is the correct way to get this done.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be colorful.

Comment: I like it to be colorful. But how to get it done

Answer (score 9):

Try following simple way, as an example I use sales order grid:

Step 1: Create **SR/ModifiedSalesOrderGrid/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_index.xml** where you can define css file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="SR_ModifiedSalesOrderGrid::css/grid.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

Step 2: Create **SR/ModifiedSalesOrderGrid/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml** for overwriting listing component

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">SR_ModifiedSalesOrderGrid/js/grid/listing</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Step 3: Create js component **SR/ModifiedSalesOrderGrid/view/adminhtml/web/js/grid/listing.js**

```
define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/grid/listing'
], function (Collection) {
    'use strict';

    return Collection.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'SR_ModifiedSalesOrderGrid/ui/grid/listing'
        },
        getRowClass: function (row) {

            if(row.status == 'complete') {
                return 'complete';
            } else if(row.status == 'closed') {
                return 'closed';
            } else if(row.status == 'processing') {
                return 'processing';
            } else {
                return 'pending';
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Step 4: Create template **SR/ModifiedSalesOrderGrid/view/adminhtml/web/template/ui/grid/listing.html**

```
<div class="admin__data-grid-wrap" data-role="grid-wrapper">
    <table class="data-grid" data-role="grid">
       <thead>
            <tr each="data: getVisible(), as: '$col'" render="getHeader()"/>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="data-row" repeat="foreach: rows, item: '$row'">
                <td outerfasteach="data: getVisible(), as: '$col'"
                    css="$parent.getRowClass($row())" click="getFieldHandler($row())" template="getBody()"/>
            </tr>
            <tr ifnot="hasData()" class="data-grid-tr-no-data">
                <td attr="colspan: countVisible()" translate="'We couldn\'t find any records.'"/>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Step 5: Create css file **SR/ModifiedSalesOrderGrid/view/adminhtml/web/css/grid.css**

```
td.complete {
    background-color: #008000;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

td.closed {
    background-color: #FF0000;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

td.processing {
    background-color: #808080;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

td.pending {
    background-color: #FFA500;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

[Download full module from here](https://github.com/sohelrana09/modified-sales-order-grid)

Answer (score 1):

You can download the free extension "Grid Colouring" to get it done)

https://extait.com/grid-colouring.html

Comment: This extension is suitable for colorizing the orders grid only and need to be modified. :(

Comment: Yeah, but if you need coloring other grids just check how it is working in this module ;)

Comment: Sure, good idea. In a few words, this extension replaces component & template of a grid to its own, where colors adding using CSS.